# Progress bar for multiple ajax requests with stages of completion. Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a simple form which when submitted validates via an ajax request. If the form checks out ok, then another ajax request is made to process the data originally submitted.

I want to build a progress bar for this. Ive found that adding this code to each ajax request returns the progress for each call separately. That makes the progress bar load to 100%, twice, quickly.

Is it possible for example for two ajax request to each fill 50% of the progress bar?... So ajax request 1 will fill up to 50% and the second will fill from 51% to 100%? Or is that crazy?

Or if three ajax calls each being responsible for 33.33% of the total percentage?

I guess we are more looking at stages of completion as well as progress.

Any ideas how this could be achieved without too much faking it?

```
var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
//Upload progress
xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
        //Do something with upload progress
        console.log('percent uploaded: ' + (percentComplete * 100));
    }
}, false);
//Download progress
xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
        //Do something with download progress
        console.log('percent downloaded: ' + (percentComplete * 100));
    }
}, false);
return xhr;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can create an array containing each ajax call. Set `<progress>` element `max` attribute to `100/array.length`. Divide `evt.loaded / evt.total` of individual `progress` event by array `.length` to set `value` of `<progress>` element. You could also use `Promise.all()`, `.then()` to process array of functions returning a `Promise` from ajax call and update `<progress>` element.

---

html

```
<label></label>
<progress value="0" min="0" max="100"></progress>
```

javascript

```
var progress = document.querySelector("progress");
var url = "/echo/html/";

function request(url) {
var len = arr.length;
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
    if (evt.lengthComputable) {   
      var percentComplete = ((evt.loaded / evt.total) * (progress.max / len)) 
                            / len;
      progress.value += percentComplete;
      console.log(progress.value, percentComplete);
      if (evt.total === evt.loaded) {
        requests += 1;
      }
      if (progress.value == progress.max && requests === len) {
        progress.previousElementSibling.innerHTML = "upload complete";
        // you could call `resolve()` here if only interested in
        // `upload` portion of request
        alert("upload complete");
      }
    }
  }, false);
  xhr.onload = function() {
     resolve(this.responseText)
  };
  xhr.onerror = reject;
  xhr.open("POST", url, true)
  xhr.send("html=" + Array(100000).fill(1).join(""));
  })
}

var arr = [], requests = 0;
arr.push(request, request, request);
Promise.all(arr.map(function(req) {
  return req(url)
}))
.then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);    
})
.catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err)
})
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/v2msL7hj/3/

Comment: This sounds good but without a code example i dont follow it 100%. I wouldn't know how to create an array of ajax calls. Its likely to be simple but i've never done it before. Any help with this would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: @Aparistar Should there be separate `<progress>` element for upload, and download?

Comment: No Im actually only interested in upload. Thanks

Comment: @Aparistar See updated post. Adjusted `progress.value += percentComplete` to line following `percentComplete` being defined

Comment: @guest271314 I can't agree with you since every file size is not exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

Well the way i had created such a progress bar was, since you want each of your function to be called one after another, that is completion of one should trigger the other, XMLHttpRequest has onreadystate change event. you can use that event to confirm that the first request got executed successfully or not, and then trigger the second one, at each change you will have progress bar incremented by whatever % you want to.

```
function postdata()
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open
        (
            "POST",
            Url,
            true
        );
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4)
        {
            //Call next function here and increment progressbar
        }
    }
}
```

hope this helps