# How to change width of a element in JavaScript, while looping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, progress-bar

I'm trying to change the width of an element in JavaScript in runtime while looping.
I have to change the width of a division to simulate a progress bar when I load the data from a loop; the problem is that the style changes only when the loop is complete.

I tried several options, but I can't figure it out.

This is the div:

```
<div class='Progress' id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>
```

And this is the function until now:

```
function AnalizzaFilename(response){
            var Completa = response.length;
            response.forEach(function(FileFisico) { 
                Singolo = incremento/Completa*100; // Percentage calculation
                /*  This will be the data for the update unnecessary now
                var dir = FileFisico['filpath'];            
                var file = FileFisico['filname'];
                var matrix = FileFisico['id'];
                var dataDoc = FileFisico['data'];
                var tipoDoc = FileFisico['TipDoc'];
                */
                $("#myBar").css("width", Singolo + "%"); //this works fine after the loop but not in runtime
            });
            $('.Progress').hide(); //hides the progress bar after the loop is complete
        }
```

Can anyone please tell what am I missing?

EDIT:
Inside that loop will going an ajax call that will not be so immediate, we are talking about 10 thousand Pdfs created, one per iteration so I need to show exactly at which percentage the process is

Comment: Makes no sense to slow down something that is almost immediate (as a quick foreach loop). Or give the false perception something takes more time which actually doesn't.  You could instead just trigger a smooth CSS animation 0..100% - on response success.

Comment: Inside that loop will going an ajax call that will not be so immediate, we are talking about 10 thousand Pdfs created, one per iteration so i need to show exactly at wich percentage the process is.

Comment: Well that's a gamechanger than! Worth mentioning it into the Question.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, i edited the question.

Comment: You're initializing a huge amount of load to the browser, Also modern browsers can handle multiple concurrent downloads. An AJAX  XMLHTTPRequest can give you a process. Nothing to do with for loops. I'm still not getting it... You're trying to load 10000 PDF to the browser? What kind of data are you fetching in thousands and why

Comment: Not for external use, this is for an application build ad hoc for the the company in wich i work. They need to create a large ammount of pdfs (one per user) every two month. So this will not download any file, this will create a file (with FPDF) and save it in local storage on the server. I need to show exactly where the procedure is, so i can avoid doubles files when they will restart the procedure if some error occours during the process (N.B  they want to know exactly the percentage; strange request, i know...

Comment: But a for loop does not represent the actual process time a server is taking into creating and saving those PDFs to the server...  I'm still not sure to understand what kind of actions you're doing on the front-end - instead of just letting the server do the entire job and notify the UI regularily about the % progress status...

Comment: Otherwise you could get some ideas from this (or similar) answers... https://stackoverflow.com/a/38173108/383904

Comment: Believe me, If I could I would show a generic loading while updating a .txt with report on this operation; anyway they asked for a progress bar linked to this loop... so... EDIT: Just saw the link you posted, i will try that tomorrow, thanks

Comment: Understand that you cannot reliably how much time a server is taking onto processing a list with a for loop on the frontend side. A for loop is almost instantaneous. Also I see no point to - first load a complete files list to the UI to just than resend back a one-by-one task back to the server - when all of it could've been done immediately by the server in the first place. Why not simply: *"Hey server, just go create those files and send me back a progress every once in a while - and eventual errors, and a "completed" when done - will ya"*.