# React - single progress bar for multiple downloads

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, download, progress-bar

I want to download files simultaneously, but I want to get the progress
of the download in a single progress bar.

I already have the code to download the assets, just need the best way to represent it.

```
Promise.all(arr.map((endpoint) => axiosInstance.get(endpoint.url,{
onDownloadProgress: (progressEvent) =>{
  let percentCompleted = Math.round(progressEvent.loaded * 100 / 
  progressEvent.total);
  console.log(progressEvent.lengthComputable);
  console.log("progress completed : " + percentCompleted);
},
responseType:"arraybuffer",
headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
}))
```

**Edit:**

The accepted answear helped me and now I have a progress bar with the percentage of all downloads simultaneously

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### After a little bit of digging, I found this:

```js
let progress = 0;
const arr = [...]; // <request_1>, <request_2>, ...<request_n>
const arrLen = arr.length;

Promise.all(
  arr.map((endpoint) => {
    let previous = 0;

    return axios.get(endpoint, {
      onDownloadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
        const current = Math.round(
          (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total / arrLen
        );

        progress += current - previous;
        console.log(progress);

        previous = current;
      },
      responseType: "arraybuffer",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });
  })
);
```

*P.S: This is a quick solution.*

###### Resources

1. [Progress bar for multiple ajax requests with stages of completion. Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38172978/progress-bar-for-multiple-ajax-requests-with-stages-of-completion-is-it-possibl)

Comment: Hi!

sorry for the late reply, but it worked! 
Now I have a percentage of all downloads